# Create viber iOS like toolbar for android app

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I would like to create viber iOS like toolbar for android. See below image for details.

[image: viber ios toolbar]

I would like to have "All" and "Groups" like two buttons in toolbar and load a respective fragment in main activity when the button is clicked.

Can anyone help me to create the layout for this toolbar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML file will be:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/corner_drawable"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="All" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/corner_drawable_1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Groups"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Drawables files will be like:

**1. corner_drawable.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

**2. corner_drawable1.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```